# New to R, would like to simulate a function 10000 times

Tags: r, function, replicate

```
PI<-0.5825702
pJ<-1-PI
s<-simulate_game(1,2)
K<-true_RA[13]-s[1]/PI
K

elo_Rating<-function(RA_i,RA_j,k) {
PI<-(1/(1+exp((RA_j-RA_i))))  # Expected score for player i
PJ<-(1/(1+exp((RA_j-RA_i))))  # Expected score for player j
new_RA_i_wins <-RA_i+ k*(1-PI) #new rankling based on wins of i,
  #used the formula which is given 
new_RA_i_defets <-RA_i-k*PI   #new rankling based on lost of i
new_RA_j_wins<-RA_j+ k*(1-PJ) #new rankling based on wins of j
new_RA_j_defets <-RA_j-k*PJ  #new rankling based on lost of j
I_wins<-round(data.frame(I_wins=c(new_RA_i_wins,new_RA_j_defets)), digits=0)
J_wins<-round(data.frame(J_wins=c(new_RA_i_defets,new_RA_i_defets)), digits=0)
df<-cbind(I_wins, J_wins)
 rownames(df) <- c('playerI', 'playerJ')
  return(df)
}
RA_i<-s[1]
RA_j<-s[2]
elo_Rating(398.333333 ,-1.666667,-681.7516)
```

I have this function and would like to simulate it 10000 times. and save a result in matrix (13 rows and 10000 columns). I know I need to use replicate. but don't know how to write a function to replicate my current function and put it in the matrix.

Comment: You could preallocate an array of 13 rows and 1000 columns and loop over it. Filling each column index with the result. Best I can do from my phone right now! :)

Comment: It would help if you can edit your example so that the sampling procedure is clear and your inputs into `elo_Rating()` track with your sampling.  Right now you get `RA_i` and `RA_j` from `simulate_game()` but it's not clear what that is, and `k` seems like it might be `K`?  But then `true_RA` is also not defined.  Your actual call to `elo_Rating()` uses hard-coded values.  It's still possible to answer your question without these fixes, but it would make your question much clearer with a little editing.

Comment: additionally: `elo_Rating()` returns a 2x2 table.  what is the relationship of that 2x2 output to the 13 rows you mention as expected output?